# The necessity of the word "that"

Tags: that

Which of the sentences is correct?

1. It will expect the client has 1 page.
2. It will expect that the client has 1 page.
3. It will expect the client has 1 a page.
4. It will expect that the client has a 1 page.

Is the word "**that**" necessary? And what about the word "**a** 1 page"? w/ or w/o

Comment: Hello, Altaula. One question at a time, please. Although 'that' is not always necessary in a that-clause after 'expect'  (I expect he will come later), using 'expect' with the subject 'it' seems inappropriate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the four examples, the second seems the most correct.

> It will expect that the client has 1 page.

If you don't use *that* then some rephrasing would commonly be used.

> It will expect the client *to have* 1 page.

If you use *a 1 page*, you should add something afterwards (*a 1-page* ***report***).

Alternatively, if you don't add anything after *page*, you can add *a* but drop *1* (*a page*) or you can replace *1* with *single* (*a single page*).

The use of *it* is strange in this isolated sentence, but, in context, might make sense. It reminds me of Golum's style of speech from *Lord of the Rings*. Or, perhaps, *it* could be a non-gender-identifying person's pronoun of choice. (Or a conscious machine or object in a speculative story.)

Lastly, it would look better in this case to write out *one* rather than to to use the number.